# scrolltop is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code for pagination as next page is triggered when i scroll to top but this is not working hope some one helps .

```
onEndless = function() {
      var url;
      $(window).off('scroll', onEndless);
      url = $('.pagination .next a').attr('href');
      $('.pagination').hide();
      if (url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 300) {
        $('.loader').show();
        return $.getScript(url, function() {
          return $(window).on('scroll', onEndless);
        });
      } else {
        return $(window).on('scroll', onEndless);
      }
    };

    $(window).on('scroll', onEndless);

    $(window).scroll();
```

Comment: You may have an issue with operator precedence. You should wrap the third  expression in your if statement with parentheses like `url && ( $(window).scrollTop() > ( $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 300 ) )`

Comment: no .. It works fine with If I changed to scrollBottom when i paginate when i scroll downwards but with scrollTop there is no use ..